# How to disable mouse support in terminal?

Tags: terminal, mouse, terminal-emulator, xfce4-terminal

I'm asking this question while using xfce4-terminal, but I'm interested in a general solution: is there a way to stop a terminal emulator announcing mouse support in consoles? I need mouse-select and copy-paste much more frequent that I need mouse support in vim or wherever.

Comment: Not an answer, but you should be able to use xfce4-terminal's own copy/paste from/to vim (shift-ctrl-c, shift-ctrl-v).

Comment: You know you can hold _Shift_ to get the normal selection right?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas if you add this as an Answer and not a Comment, I'll accept it :) I didn't know about the Shift!

@ goldilocks: yes, I knew about shift-ctrl-c, it's not directly related to what I wanted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to use the normal mouse selection while *xterm mouse-tracking* is enabled. That works in all terminal emulators that I know (`xterm`, `vte` (like `xfce-terminal`) or `rxvt`-based ones).

In `vim` specifically, `mouse` is normally  not enabled by default in terminals. So there's probably a `set mouse=a` somewhere in you `~/.vimrc` or your OS-supplied system vimrc. You can always add:

```
set mouse=
```

to your `~/.vimrc` to disable it. Or:

```
if !has("gui_running")
  set mouse=
endif
```

to avoid disabling it for the GUI versions of `vim`.

Mouse support is (sort of) advertised in the `terminfo` database with the `kmous` capability. Now, not all applications rely on that to decide whether to enable mouse tracking or not.

You could redefine the entry for your terminal (in a local terminfo database) to remove that capability:

```
infocmp -1x | grep -v kmous= | TERMINFO=~/.terminfo tic -x -
export TERMINFO=~/.terminfo
```

For applications using `ncurses`, it's enough to set the `XM` *user-defined* capability (not documented in `terminfo(5)` but mentioned in `curs_caps(5)` and `curs_mouse(3)`) to the empty string. That doesn't prevent the application from handling mouse events if they're sent by the terminal, but that prevents the application from sending the sequence that enters the mouse tracking mode. So you can combine both with:

```
infocmp -1x |
  sed '/kmous=/d;/XM=/d;$s/$/XM=,/' |
  TERMINFO=~/.terminfo tic -x -
export TERMINFO=~/.terminfo
```

Comment: Are you sure about the terminfo solution? I just tried it on URxvt (with TERM=xterm-256color) but Aptitude is still responding to mouse clicks, which is super annoying. I wished URxvt had an option to disable mouse reporting entirely. I never use it and gets in the way more often than not.

Comment: @Tobia, see edit.

Comment: The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_mouse.3x.html#h2-BUGS) gives the information (and has, since [August 2001](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20010825)).

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDickey, looks like I also messed up my test cases. See edit.

Comment: If you use the **`-1`** option of infocmp (single column), the sed expression could be simplified.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, thanks. I thought it wasn't portable, while it seems it actually is and `-x` is not. I take it on systems where terminfo (tic) doesn't support user-defined capabilities (-x), the only option it to use a terminfo entry without `xterm` in the name and description?

Comment: Offhand, on **those** systems, the curses library doesn't know about the xterm mouse protocol that we're talking about (so the terminfo would be irrelevant).

Comment: @ThomasDickey, but what about applications using ncurses on systems that have a terminfo (and curses) without user-defined attributes. Or does ncurses always installs its own terminfo database which it uses in place of the system's one? I do remember installing ncurses on Solaris decades ago, but don't remember the details.

Comment: ncurses can do either, and its extensions are invisible to the system's tic/infocmp.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, OK. Do you mean that if I use `export TERMINFO=~/.terminfo; ncurses-tic -x file` with that `XM=`, applications using the system's `curses` will still be able to read the `~/.terminfo/m/myterm` and just ignore that `XM` capability?

Comment: yes (short).  Solaris is simple.  Some old systems need ncurses configure [`--with-caps`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/INSTALL#L838).  See [this page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-slang.html#cause_terminfo_standard).

Comment: Thanks for the `shift` key trick; this just saved me when I was trying to copy/paste an error message from a curses program that had grabbed the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following two lines at the end of /etc/vim/vimrc :

```
set mouse=
set ttymouse=
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m using this patch:

```
--- a/src/vteseq.cc 2020-01-25 21:39:47.737317745 +0100
+++ b/src/vteseq.cc 2020-01-25 21:40:12.811424242 +0100
@@ -462,18 +462,7 @@
 void
 Terminal::update_mouse_protocol() noexcept
 {
-        if (m_modes_private.XTERM_MOUSE_ANY_EVENT())
-                m_mouse_tracking_mode = MOUSE_TRACKING_ALL_MOTION_TRACKING;
-        else if (m_modes_private.XTERM_MOUSE_BUTTON_EVENT())
-                m_mouse_tracking_mode = MOUSE_TRACKING_CELL_MOTION_TRACKING;
-        else if (m_modes_private.XTERM_MOUSE_VT220_HIGHLIGHT())
-                m_mouse_tracking_mode = MOUSE_TRACKING_HILITE_TRACKING;
-        else if (m_modes_private.XTERM_MOUSE_VT220())
-                m_mouse_tracking_mode = MOUSE_TRACKING_SEND_XY_ON_BUTTON;
-        else if (m_modes_private.XTERM_MOUSE_X10())
-                m_mouse_tracking_mode = MOUSE_TRACKING_SEND_XY_ON_CLICK;
-        else
-                m_mouse_tracking_mode = MOUSE_TRACKING_NONE;
+   m_mouse_tracking_mode = MOUSE_TRACKING_NONE;

         m_mouse_smooth_scroll_delta = 0.0;
```

vte doesn’t care about my mouse anymore, so vim isn’t aware that I have one.

Comment: Can you tell us where this patch comes from, and explain how to apply it and what it does? … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

In xterm/uxterm I was able to disable sending mouse position changes with this patch:

```
--- a/button.c
@@ -261,6 +261,7 @@ SendMousePosition(XtermWidget xw, XEvent *event)
 {
     XButtonEvent *my_event = (XButtonEvent *) event;
     Bool result = False;
+    return False;
 
     switch (okSendMousePos(xw)) {
     case MOUSE_OFF:
```

Answer (score 0):

For `xterm` at least (it does not seem to work with `urxvt`), you can "disable mouse" by running it as

```shell
xterm -xrm xterm*allowMouseOps:false
```